# $\int_{-1}^1\frac{y}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The solution says that we will get this $$\left[-\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\pi} \right]^1_{-1} $$.

How do we get this definite integral. I know we are integrating an odd function over symmetric domain so the answer will be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{y}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy$$
Substitute $u=\sqrt{1-y^2}\implies du=-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$. Then

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{y}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy=-\int_{\text{limits}}\frac{du}{\pi}=-\left[\frac u\pi\right]_{\text{limits}}=\left[\frac{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\pi}\right]_{-1}^1$$ as required.

The motivation behind this substitution is to get rid of the awkward denominator (also by knowing with experience that the integrand is the exact derivative of this function, but I feel like this is a natural substitution to make even if you do not know this).

Comment: I made the substitution $ u=1-y^2 $ then my bounds became 0 and 0. What went wrong

Comment: In this example I ignored what the bounds become (they become 0 for my substitution too) and I just went back to the $y$ bounds. I believe that what you'd have got is: $$\int_0^0\frac{-2({1-u})}{\pi\sqrt u}\,du$$ This has both limits of $0$ but the actual integrand is not defined at $0$ - you get $\frac{-2}{0}$. So this is not a good substitution.

Comment: With my substitution, you'd get $$\int_0^0\frac{du}\pi$$ which also has 
both limits of $0$, but this time my actual integrand exists - I get $$\left[\frac u\pi\right]_0^0$$ which I can evaluate to be $0$. Or I could say both limits are the same, and the integral is defined at this limit, so this integral is $0$. There are numerous ways of showing that this integral is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$I = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{y}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\frac{d}{dy}(1-y^2)}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy $$

$$I  = -\frac{1}{2}\left[(1-y^2)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot\frac{1}{\pi}\right]_{-1}^{1} =\left[-\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\pi}\right]_{-1}^{1}$$

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is

$$\frac {-1}{\pi}\frac {-2y}{2\sqrt {1-y^2}} $$

but $$\int \frac {du}{2\sqrt {u}}=\sqrt {u} $$

observe and finish.
the final result is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = 1-y^2$, then $du = -2y ~dy$ so that 
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{y}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \frac{\frac{-1}{2}du }{\pi\sqrt{u}} = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{y=-1}^{y=1} u^{\frac{-1}{2}}du = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(2u^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)_{y=-1}^{y=1}\\
&=-\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\pi}\right)_{y=-1}^{y=1}
\end{align}

Comment: wouldn't the bounds change to 0 and 0 after you make that substitution? this would lead to an error

Answer (score 1):

The integral equal to $0$ because the function is odd.

By the way, we have no any problem with substitution in primitive function  $y=\pm1$.

Comment: Yes I know that, but how do we integrate the function in the title to get the function in the solution

Comment: @matt It's all right! I don't see any problem.